# Sequelize при создании миграций создается пустой шаблон

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Имею уже готовых 2 модели

User и Order с полями

когда создаю файл миграции

> sequelize migration:create --name="create_users_and_orders"

получаю файл

> New migration was created at 20170319085303-create_users_and_orders.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    /*
      Add altering commands here.
      Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

      Example:
      return queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER });
    */
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    /*
      Add reverting commands here.
      Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

      Example:
      return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
    */
  }
};
```

А поля я сам создавать должен, зачем тогда нужна генерация миграции? Gустой файл я могу и сам создать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я в итоге понял, файлы миграции создаются пустые, точнее с базовым шаблоном, всю "логику" писать самому.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле если ты хочешь, чтобы миграции сразу генерировались. Нужно создавать модели через генератор.
Например:

`node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name ModelName --attributes attribute1:data_type,attribute2:data_type`

Тогда сгенерируется и модель и миграция.